# Display image if database value is greater than

Tags: php, database, image, if-statement, show

I'm creating a math questions website. The user can answer questions on different math areas. When they log in and answer questions, their stats are stored in a database ie: (For each area) the amount of correct answers and the amount of incorrect answers.

There will be a page the user can go to when they are logged in to view all these stats. I also want to include a "trophy room" where the user will get "trophies" for certain achievements, such as answering 20 questions correctly.

I thought i would have all the images (trophies) in an area and have them set to display:none.

My Question: I'm not too sure how I would display the images/trophies in the trophy room page when the the database value is greater than a certain value. Any ideas on how I can do this? I'm fairly new to php, a php if statement perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each time the user passes a condition for a trophy, you can add their information, along with the trophy name to the database.

After that, you can use a query like the following to pull out their trophies and display them on the trophy page.

```
SELECT `trophy` FROM `trophies` WHERE `user_id` = ?;
```

Of course, this is just an example. You can structure your table however you like.

Also, please use either [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) for querying your database using PHP. A lot of tend to find older tutorials using mysql_* functions, which have been officially deprecated. This means that there is no longer any official support for them, and they will be completely removed in the future.